# URL not getting mapped with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am configuring a basic Spring MVC project and I don't understand why a URL is not getting caught by my controller.

This is in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This is the servlet context:

```
<annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.lh.mvcex" />
```

And this is the HomeController

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "home", "/home.jsp" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home_jsp(Locale locale, Model model) {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

The URLs / and /home are correctly mapped to my home.jsp resource, but not the third (home.jsp), which gives me 404.

Question 1: why?

Furthermore, I would like to map a request (let's say /customhome) that does not leverage the view resolver to return a page, but rather I want it to return plain html.
Question 2: how can I return plain html?

Finally, I would like to map a request (let's say /statichome) that returns a resource home.html in the resources folder.
Question 3: how can I return the static page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This servlet mapping pattern

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

is a default url pattern. It will match any request that wasn't matched by any other `url-pattern`. Presumably your Servlet container has a `servlet-mapping` of

```
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

for its JSP handling servlet. This takes precedence over your `DispatcherServlet` if the requested URL has a `.jsp` extension.

You can use `@ResponseBody` and return a `String` containing the HTML. **I do not recommend doing this. Separate your Java from your HTML.**

Again with `@ResponseBody`, you can return a `Resource` object identifying the resource you want serialized to the response body.

Comment: Thanks. Concerning the third answer, how do I concretely return my static resource (e.g. an html or an image)?

Comment: @Manu You annotate your method with `@ResponseBody`, you create an appropriate [`Resource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) object that identifies the resource, and return it.

Comment: Ok, so something like Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("home.html") is what I need. Now, rather than RestController annotated classes, I could just use this configuration to return json when mapping REST-compliant urls.

Comment: @Manu `@RestController` is just an implicit `@ResponseBody` on all `@RequestMapping` methods.

Comment: I was noticing that if I try to map /home.html, I get the same response as with /home and /. Is this a matter of url similarity, where the suffix is just ignored (differently from suffixing .jsp, which is intercepted by the container)?

Comment: @manu Yes. Check out `PathMatchConfigurer` and its `useSuffixPatternMatch` property.